# Average quantity in statistical mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I'm tasked with the following problem:

A peptide is dissolved in a solvent.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be degrees of freedom of the peptide and solvent respectively, and let

$$W(X) = -kT \log \left[C \int \mathrm{d} Y  \, \mathrm{e}^{-U(X,Y)/kT}\right]$$

be the mean force acting on the peptide. Let $A(X)$ be a function of the peptide degrees of freedom; then how can we write $\langle A \rangle$ as a function of $W$?

My issue with this problem is that I cannot see quite how to calculate averages of some unknown function of $X$. I can use Boltzmann statistics to calculate the average energy, but don't know how to translate this into an expression for $\langle A \rangle$. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking up [ensemble averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_average_(statistical_mechanics)) or [expectation values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)?